# Phython: missing-function-docstring (pylance)

Tags: python, pep8, pylance

Im getting the message from pylace at my function. What to do?

```
def retangulo(larg, comp):
   
    area = larg * comp
   
    print(f'A área de um terreno {larg} x {comp} é {area}.')
```

[docstringpylint(missing-function-docstring)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riIcy.png)

I am expecting to understand how to write python the "right way".

Comment: your question is not very clear what you are trying to do here, can you please add more details to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... write python the "right way".

That is certainly commendable.
Not sure I'd want to insist on a """docstring""" on
*every* function though, since some, like this one,
are already pretty self-explanatory.

The missing-function-docstring diagnostic is inviting you to add a single
sentence of documentation, such as this:

```
def retangulo(larg, comp):
    """Displays the area of a rectangle, given its two sides."""
    area = larg * comp
    print(f'A área de um terreno {larg} x {comp} é {area}.')
```

---

Consider [linting](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) with `flake8` instead.
It is not too picky.
When I find it complaining,
I usually agree with its complaint,
so I fix things up at once to ensure it remains silent.

---

Consider [running](https://pypi.org/project/black/) `black .` before linting,
to automatically fix up minor whitespace issues.

---

Consider throwing in an optional type hint or two:

```
def retangulo(larg: int, comp: int) -> int:
```

Remember that python does not do any runtime
checking / enforcement of types,
so `retangulo(1, math.pi)` would still "work".
The [mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy/) static analysis checker
would dutifully complain about such a call.

Or, since the concepts of length and area
are defined across non-negative real numbers,
it would no doubt be better to declare like this:

```
def retangulo(larg: float, comp: float) -> float:
```

You don't *have* to use type hints,
and if you do you certainly don't have to use
them *everywhere*.

But in addition to their concise documentation
value to humans, and the linting value of a `mypy` run,
they can play very nicely with IDEs, such as PyCharm.
When you type `foo.` CTRL-SPACE and hope to see
some auto-completion suggestions, the type of `foo`
matters. And hints help the IDE to make
relevant suggestions.
For example, if the IDE knows that `foo` is a regex,
it might suggest `.findall(` as a completion,
which is quite different from what it would
do with a `str` variable.

Comment: Being "self-explenatory" is not enough, given that doc-strings are/can be used to generate documentation.

Comment: Granted. It is a per-project policy matter. (And we still wouldn't insist that `def _private_helper():` needs a docstring.) I doubted that OP has gotten to the level where such nuanced details would affect how he authors new functions. I try to meet the audience where they are.